# How to verify a pattern between columns , row by row, in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv

So I have a CSV file with two Columns I want to compare.

The columns correspond to each other and each adjacent row between the two columns should follow a certain pattern.

For example:

A |  B

1 -> 2

3 -> 4

1 -> 2

3 -> 4

Every time there is a 1 in a row within column A, there should be a 2 within the adjacent row in column B.

I want to write a script that will alert me if there are any instances where there is a 1 in row A and there ISNT a 2 in row B.

This is what I have now:

```
# Prep Work 

#The Toolbox:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy as sp
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns #plotting
import os #filepaths
import glob
import getpass # Login information
import math 
import sys

unane = getpass.getuser()

#Paths:
path2proj = os.path.join('C:', os.sep, 'Users', unane, 'Documents', 'Mclean','Expts','PST', '')
path2data = os.path.join(path2proj,'Data','')
path2asys = os.path.join(path2proj,'Analysis', '')
path2figs = os.path.join(path2asys, 'figures', '')
path2hddm = os.path.join(path2asys, 'modeling', '')

extension = 'csv'


#Saved list of filrnames within "all_filenames"
#The glob module finds all the pathnames matching a specified pattern based on rules predetermined. Results are returned in arbitrary order 

all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]





combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames]) 

"Combined_csv.csv"  

combined_csv.to_csv("combined_csv.csv",index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')

df = pd.read_csv(path2data + 'combined_csv.csv')

df['left_stim_number'].equals(df['right_stim_number'])
```

Comment: When looping through rows, save the values in column A in a dictionary with the corresponding value IF it isn't already there, ELSE just test that the value in the dict corresponds to the current one.

Comment: . Apologies for my poor explanation. The problem I am trying to solve is comparing rows within column A to Column B given a certain pattern. For example in row 1 of Column A if there is a "1" there should be a "2" in row 1 of column B. I am trying to write a script that would return an error if there was a "1" in row 1 of column A but not a "2" in row 1 of column B. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question right, Column B is always expected to be grater than Column A.
ie, B=A+1 in this case.

I would recommend you to create a new column to store the result of the comparison between Column A and B ie, C = True if A and B satisfies the condition, else C = False.
Here df['check_stim_number'] will be the new column with values True or False.

```
df['check_stim_number'] = df['left_stim_number']+1 == df['right_stim_number']
```

Comment: The New column is a good idea. Apologies for my poor explanation. The problem I am trying to solve is comparing rows within column A to Column B given a certain pattern. For example in row 1 of Column A if there is a "1" there should be a "2" in row 1 of column B. I am trying to write a script that would return an error if there was a "1" in row 1 of column A but not a "2" in row 1 of column B. Does that make sense?

Comment: If you write a script to return error when the condition is not satisfied between the two given columns, it'll return error at the 1st occurrence of the  issue, it will not continue for the rest of the rows/data. Is this what you are trying to do? Also,checkout User-defined Exceptions in python.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am trying to do , but I would like to have it return errors for any occurrence of the issues (not stop at the first error found). Do you know how to accomplish this ? I will look into user defined exceptions. Thank you for helping me

Comment: So you don't want to interrupt the execution on occurrence of the error. Where would you want to store the error details? a file? on the console?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure I understand correctly, but if you just want the rows of the dataframe df in which column left_stim_number is not equal to right_stim_number you can simply do

```
df.loc[df['left_stim_number'] != df['right_stim_number'],:]
```

EDIT: the above obviously does not check for certain values. If you want to check if left_stim_number is 1 and then if right_stim_number is 2, you could do this:

```
mask = (df['left_stim_number'] == 1) & (df['right_stim_number'] != 2)
df.loc[mask,:]
```

Comment: Sorry If I wasn't clear enough. What I'm trying to do is see if there is a situation in any of the columns where 1 does not correspond to 2. If this happens I would want to return an error that highlights which row had a problem.